# Python homework help request

Tags: python

I need a little input on why I'm not getting the desired result from my code.

Here's the code:

```
def main():
    SEAT_LIMIT_A=300
    print("Enter the total amount of tickets sold for Section A")
    sectionA=getTickets(0, SEAT_LIMIT_A)
    print("The total amount of tickets sold for section A is",sectionA)

def getTickets(ticket, SEAT_LIMIT):
    ticket=int(input("Enter:"))
    ticketsInvalid(ticket, SEAT_LIMIT)
    return ticket

def ticketsInvalid(ticket, SEAT_LIMIT):
    while ticket <0 or ticket > SEAT_LIMIT:
        print ("Error: The amount of tickets sold can't be less than 0 or more than",SEAT_LIMIT)
        ticket=int(input("Please enter the correct amount here: "))
        return ticket

main()
```

I basically need to get the number of tickets sold for a section in a movie theater, and then I need a validation loop to verify if the number entered is not less than or more than the seat limit for the section (in this case it's A, but I also need to implement more into the program once I figure out this section).  My professor wants us to create general functions to help complete this process for any section that needs to be checked.  She wants the main function to ask what was sold by calling the getTickets function, and then she wants the input from the getTicket function to be passed on to the ticketsInvalid function, so it can be checked, then she wants it to be passed back to the main function to be displayed.

Here's an output of a sample test of my code:

```
Enter the total amount of tickets sold for Section A
Enter:400
Error: The amount of tickets sold can't be less than 0 or more than 300
Please enter the correct amount here: 200
The total amount of tickets sold for section A is 400
```

I can't seem to figure out how I can get the amount entered at the validation loop to display in the main function correctly.  Any help without terribly altering my code would be very much appreciated.  I could easily complete this program with having to pass arguments from function to function, but that's what she wants...  Sorry for the long post, there's just a lot of bull rules that she wants us to implement.  I am a complete newbie to programming, so please keep that in mind when you write your solutions/explanations :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the method `getTickets(ticket, SEAT_LIMIT)`, you are returning old value of ticket. The new value returned from `ticketsInvalid(ticket, SEAT_LIMIT)` is unused.

So make a small modification in getTickets() method.

```
def getTickets(ticket, SEAT_LIMIT):
    ticket=int(input("Enter:"))
    return ticketsInvalid(ticket, SEAT_LIMIT)
```

Comment: Oh my God, thank you so much...  You're a life saver.  I've been ramming my head into a wall trying to figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

when you assign new value to ticket variable in ticketsInvalid. It create new int object and assign to ticket variable. and you are not using return value of fun ticketsInvalid in getTickets.

Hope you got it.